# Media server on DC or on standalone media server?

Tags: domain, domain-controller, backupexec

Our organisation currently has Backup Exec 11d installed on the Windows Server 2008 r2 domain controller. I'm currently performing a domain migration which involves transferring all roles etc from the old DC to the new DC.

Initially Backup Exec was going to be transferred from the old DC to the new one. Having thought about it, would having BE installed on the DC be a bad move? If our DC was to fail, it would involve installed BE on another server before being able to restore the DC.

What sort of set ups do you guys utilise within your organisation? Do you have a standalone server for Backups?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft's official line is DCs should server no other purpose. They voilate this a bit with SBS for simplicity, but for any other situation it should be it's own box.

We have a box dedicated solely to doing backups.